# The `device` argument should be set by using `torch.device` or passing a string as an argument

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

My data iterator currently runs on the CPU as `device=0` argument is deprecated. But I need it to run on the GPU with the rest of the model etc.

Here is my code:

```
pad_idx = TGT.vocab.stoi["<blank>"]
model = make_model(len(SRC.vocab), len(TGT.vocab), N=6)
model = model.to(device)
criterion = LabelSmoothing(size=len(TGT.vocab), padding_idx=pad_idx, smoothing=0.1)
criterion = criterion.to(device)
BATCH_SIZE = 12000
train_iter = MyIterator(train, device, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                        repeat=False, sort_key=lambda x: (len(x.src), len(x.trg)),
                        batch_size_fn=batch_size_fn, train=True)
valid_iter = MyIterator(val, device, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                        repeat=False, sort_key=lambda x: (len(x.src), len(x.trg)),
                        batch_size_fn=batch_size_fn, train=False)
#model_par = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=devices)
```

The above code gives this error:

```
The `device` argument should be set by using `torch.device` or passing a string as an argument. This behavior will be deprecated soon and currently defaults to cpu.
The `device` argument should be set by using `torch.device` or passing a string as an argument. This behavior will be deprecated soon and currently defaults to cpu.
```

I have tried passing in `'cuda'` as an argument instead of `device=0` but I receive this error:

```
<ipython-input-50-da3b1f7ed907> in <module>()
    10     train_iter = MyIterator(train, 'cuda', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    11                             repeat=False, sort_key=lambda x: (len(x.src), len(x.trg)),
---> 12                             batch_size_fn=batch_size_fn, train=True)
    13     valid_iter = MyIterator(val, 'cuda', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    14                             repeat=False, sort_key=lambda x: (len(x.src), len(x.trg)),

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'batch_size'
```

I have also tried passing in `device` as an argument. Device being defined as `device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')`

But receive the same error as just above.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pad_idx = TGT.vocab.stoi["<blank>"]
model = make_model(len(SRC.vocab), len(TGT.vocab), N=6)
model = model.to(device)
criterion = LabelSmoothing(size=len(TGT.vocab), padding_idx=pad_idx, smoothing=0.1)
criterion = criterion.to(device)
BATCH_SIZE = 12000
train_iter = MyIterator(train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, device = torch.device('cuda'),
                        repeat=False, sort_key=lambda x: (len(x.src), len(x.trg)),
                        batch_size_fn=batch_size_fn, train=True)
valid_iter = MyIterator(val, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, device = torch.device('cuda'),
                        repeat=False, sort_key=lambda x: (len(x.src), len(x.trg)),
                        batch_size_fn=batch_size_fn, train=False)
```

After lot's of trial and error I managed to set `device` as  `device = torch.device('cuda')` instead of `device=0`

Comment: @codeslord It was a long time ago but I'm pretty sure I was playing around with the Annotated Transformer [blog post from Harvard NLP](https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html)

Comment: I know. I was asking because I was very interested in your own implementation of it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

My current pytorch version `1.0.1` and previous version `0.4` work well with string and `torch.device`:

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor(1)
print(x.to('cuda:0')) # no problem
print(x.to(torch.device('cuda:0')) # no problem as well
```